# android studio add record and Update problem

Tags: php, sql-server, android-studio

I've just learned in android studio and PHP using SQL Server Database.
I got a problem with adding records also update records. Every time I tried it's giving me this error.

Can someone solve my problem

> Content-Type: text/javascript
>   2020-03-11 19:27:36.797 3320-3601/com.sna.crudebiz D/OkHttp: {"type":"exception","message":"Call to undefined action: ","where":"everywhere"}
>   2020-03-11 19:27:36.797 3320-3601/com.sna.crudebiz D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (80-byte body)
>   2020-03-11 19:27:36.857 3320-3320/com.sna.crudebiz W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for result

I keep geting these error while doing my createRecord function below :

```
public function createRecord(stdClass $params)
{
    //$_db = $this->__construct();
            $_db = mssql_connect("SAV30","dna","joker");
            mssql_select_db("TRAINING", $_db);

        $nama=$params->nama;
        $email=$params->email;  
        $notelp=$params->notelp;
        $alamat=$params->alamat;
        $foto=$params->foto;

        $success = mssql_query("INSERT INTO kontak(nama,email,notelp,alamat,foto) VALUES ('$nama','$email','$notelp','$alamat','$foto')");

        //$success = odbc_execute($stmt,array( $nama,$email,$notelp,$alamat,$foto));
    if ($success == 1){
        $params->success=1;
       /* if(isset($_FILES)){
            $temp_file = $_FILES['namafoto']['tmp_name'];
            if (move_uploaded_file($temp_file, 'C:/xampp/htdocs/recycle/foto/'.$params->foto)) {
                $params->msgfilektp='';
            } else {
                $params->msgfilektp='tidak menulis file';
            }
        }*/

    }else{
        $params->success=0;
        $params->msg="failed to save kontak";
    }

    return $params;
}
```